# System.InvalidCastException in foreach

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

im making an app in Visual Studio uwp and have a stack panel to store usercontrol objects. I want to access the array of the usercontrols within the stackpanel with a foreach loop. There is an error that says that it could not convert a button to: "Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' to type 'PopNotes.NotiObject'.'" Does anyone know what the problem is?

code:

```
ArrayList notiList = new ArrayList();
    
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int count = 0;
    
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            notificationController();
    
            foreach (NotiObject noti in itemsPanel.Children)
            {
                notiList.Add(noti);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(noti);
            }
    
    
        }
```

Comment: @Trevor could you mind convert above comment as an answer for this thread? it looks solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is an error that says that it could not convert a button to: "Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' to type 'PopNotes.NotiObject."

You're seeing this happen because the `itemsPanel.Children` collection contains other elements besides `NotiObject`. In your loop you're specifically saying for every `NotiObject` in `itemsPanel.Children`, **but** not every element is a `NotiObject` in that collection.

To fix the error you have to check the type since it could be any element. There are a few different ways, but I will list one approach.

```
foreach (NotiObject noti in itemsPanel.Children.Where(c => c is NotiObject))
{
   notiList.Add(noti);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(noti);
}
```

In the above example, I'm using [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) to filter for only `NotiObject`. Now your `foreach` is complete because each object from the `Enumerable.Where` is a type of `NotiObject`.